# Why does eval() not work for imported functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval

**In React, why does eval() only work for functions that are defined within the same file, but not for imported functions?**

In my code example, `alertY` is an imported function and `alertX` is defined within the same file. When the function name is passed to `onClick`, both `alertX` and `alertY` works.

However, when the function is directly called inside eval as a string and then passed to `onClick`, only `alertX` works. `alertY` caused a ReferenceError as follows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: alertY is not defined
    at eval (eval at onClick (index.js? [sm]:13)
```

> src/index.js

```
import { alertY } from "./alertY";

function alertX() {
  alert("x");
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={alertX}>alertX</button>
      <button onClick={alertY}>alertY</button>

      <button onClick={() => eval(`alertX()`)}>evalX</button>
      <button onClick={() => eval(`alertY()`)}>evalY</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> src/alertY.js

```
export function alertY() {
  alert("y");
}
```

[Code Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-moser-qtz4b)

Second question: As shown in Mhd's answer, why does `import * as alerts from "./alertY"` work while `import { alertY } from "./alertY"` doesn't?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Isn't export/import in strict mode?

Comment: I believe so. May I know what are the implications (i.e. does that cause imported functions to be undefined?) I have googled but not much is said about eval. Thanks!

Comment: http://whereswalden.com/2011/01/10/new-es5-strict-mode-support-new-vars-created-by-strict-mode-eval-code-are-local-to-that-code-only/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Making_eval_and_arguments_simpler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
import * as alerts from "./alertY";

function alertX() {
  alert("x");
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={alertX}>alertX</button>
      <button onClick={alerts.alertY}>alertY</button>

      <button onClick={() => eval(`alertX()`)}>evalX</button>
      <button onClick={() => eval(`alerts.alertY()`)}>evalY</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hmm that works. May I know the reasoning behind it? Thanks.

Comment: @t.c All I could find about the reason was this: https://www.exratione.com/2015/12/es6-use-of-import-property-from-module-is-not-a-great-plan/